# Как запретить ввод символов & не больше определенного кол-ва символов в Python?

Tags: mysql, python, telegram-bot

Пишу бота на Python (библиотека **pyTelegramAPIBot**).

Встал вопрос в том, что когда происходят команды с `UPDATE` в ***БД***, то если ввести что-то неверно, например:

передавать `VARCHAR` в `INT`

передавать значения для `UPDATE`, которых не существует.

То мы получим ошибку. Хочу узнать, каким методом проще решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Мы **не можем ограничить ввод пользователя (тем более в стороннем приложении)**, мы можем только **работать с полученными значениями**, и, если нас что-то не устроило, просить пользователя ввести команду заново (можно также дать рекомендации).

Вот некоторые функции, которые могут помочь:

- `isdigit()` - проверка на то, состоит ли строка только из чисел (строка с префиксами `+`, `-`, с запятыми, точками и т.д. вернёт `False`)
- `isalpha()` - проверка на то, состоит ли строка только из букв
- `len('Тест')` - получение длины строки
- `float('1.23')` - преобразование строки к числу float
- `int('123')` - преобразование строки к числу int
- `'Это тестовая строка'.startswith('Это')` - проверка на то, начинается ли строка с указанного слова (регистр учитывается)
- `'Это тестовая строка'.endswith('строка')` - проверка на то, заканчивается ли строка на указанное слово (регистр учитывается)
- `'строка' in 'Это тестовая строка'` - проверка на наличие подстроки
- `'Это тестовая строка'.upper()` - приведение строки к верхнему регистру
- `'Это тестовая строка'.lower()` - приведение строки к нижнему регистру
- `'эТО тЕсТоВая СтРокА'.capitalize()` - переводит первый символ строки в верхний регистр, а все остальные - в нижний.